# Convert a leading zero number into a string i.e 015 to "015"

Tags: javascript

I have a problem converting a leading zero number into a string

input:

```
function numToString(num) {
num = num + "";
return num;
}
numToString(015); // outputs "13"
```

Output:

```
numToString(015); // outputs "13"
```

Desired Output:

```
numToString(015); // outputs "15"
```

Comment: Why not writing it as 15 in the first place?

Comment: @lumio because the input should be a number at the beginning

Comment: 15 is a number. Or am I missing something

Comment: js will recognize any number with a leading zero (and no 8s or 9s) to octal

Comment: All your numbers are integers?

Comment: How is the function going to be used? Where is `015` coming from "in the field"?

Comment: I want to pass in a number then convert it into a string so that I can use `parseInt(num, 10)`. hope this makes sense.

Comment: Yes @CommercialSuicide

Comment: @Kira Not really; if you start out with a number, why are you converting it to a string, then parsing it to an int?

Comment: It doesn't. When it is a number in the first place you don't need to convert it :) when it comes from a input field it is already a string. Doing `parseInt( input, 10 )` would do the trick.

Comment: Would a complex solution work for you? Or you are looking for something simple. I am guessing you are getting numbers like 0xxx etc. Hence basically it always gets converted to octal ?

Comment: I need the number to be a string so that I can use string methods to loop over it, converting it array using `str.split("")` ...etc

Comment: Passing a number is **Obligatory**

Comment: @UG_ Yes! you are right

Comment: @Kira Checkout the updated answer that meets to your code issue.

Comment: @kira Is your problem solved?

Answer (score 2):

> Number 015 in octal representation of number 13.

You cannot have prefix as 0 and treat them to base 10. If you want it to print as 15 just pass

numToString(15); or numToString(017);

**EDIT:**

If you really want to print octal as string modify your code as below,

```
function numToString(num) {
num = num.toString(8) + "";
return num;
}

numToString(015); // outputs "15"
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not as stated. Unless you are using `eval` to evaluate some code put together at run time, `numToString(015);` is something you as the programmer typed in, and `015` is a numeric source code literal converted into a a number when the script is compiled.

A decimal numeric literal for an integer must start with a non zero digit. In strict mode, starting an integer with `0` will throw an error:

```js
function f() {
    "use strict"
    return 015
}
f()
```

The octal syntax for a numeric literal (integer) which starts with a '0' and is followed by octal digits is now classified as a *LegacyOctalIntegerLiteral* as defined in appendix B.1.1 of the ES6 ECMAScript standard. Legacy octal literals are not available in strict mode.

Note that the syntax used to convert a string into a number, say by applying a unary + to a string is not the same as numeric literals placed in source code. String numeric decimal integers may start with a '0':

```js
console.log( +"015")
```

So the annoying answer to your question is to not type a leading '0' in when writing a decimal integer in source. A more complicated answer is that when parsing string values to get the number, parsing should account for what is deemed to be valid input.

If you want to test if a string can be converted into a (decimal) number in its entirety, try

```
var num = + stringValue;
if( isNaN(num) {
    // stringValue edoes not convert to a number
    // If it starts with a number it has left over characters.
}
```